# Validating textbox value using rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I need some help to validate my input field using JavaScript.

1. I want to allow a single value like `abc`
2. I want to allow multiple values only when they are comma separated like `abc,abc`
3. I don't want to allow values without comma separated like `abcabc`

The Problem is this code is validating for single value and whether multiple values have comma or not but it is also taking multiple values without comma as a single value.

Note: The length of the value may vary

```
var x = document.getElementById('name');
if (x && x.indexOf(',') > -1) {
    reg.$setValidity("Validator", true)
} else {
    reg.$setValidity("Validator", false)
}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery & AngularJS? Also, include complete code.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple value which are not comma separated, are there keywords from which value is to choosen?

Comment: I mean what is the rule to make sure it not a single value but a multiple value which is not comma separated

Comment: it's not trivial trying to check for multiple values, especially using such a vague description. You need to define the rules in a lot more absolute terms as to what constitutes a *multiple*

Comment: I am using AngularJS... Value is like vxa0001247 this is a single value and when i say multiple values separated by comma it will be vxa0001247,vxa0001248,vxa0001249,vxa0001250... If there is no comma in between it is just like a single value

Comment: How are you distinguishing between a legitimate single value such as abc and an illegitimate one such as abcabc. Is there a certain length that you could use as a check?

Comment: @ Crhistian Ramirez That is the problem i have to distinguish between those two and length varies